# How did the heroes of the Galactica get out of the Tomb of Athena?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

When the main protagonists of the Galactica enter the Tomb of Athena and they apply the Arrow of Apollo by giving it to the archer,

> the tomb is shut closed and they appear on a green field surrounded by magical looking obelisks.

There appears to be no door back; after all, they could be anywhere, not really in the Tomb. I was originally thinking they won't ever return to tell the story when I was watching that episode.

They did return though. How did they do it? Did I miss the way out, or was it handwaved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It was handwaved.** There doesn't seem to be an explanation in the episode (or after) but it's pretty likely that they weren't physically transported to another chamber, they were simply immersed in an extremely realistic [hologram](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQNk6VMg9xs&feature=youtu.be&t=2m29s), a technology which we know is plausible within the BSG universe.

That being the case, the most likely resolution is that they turned off the display, either by removing the arrow or simply by stepping outside the stones.  At that point, the door presumably opened itself up again or failing that, they just forced the door open with brute strength.

Since they were in no immediate danger, there's no mileage (from a storytelling perspective) in scripting a scene where they make their way back up to the Galactica.

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but I am rewatching and just noticed this. It was some sort of hologram and they presumably turned it off and walked out, like Valorum said.

In season 2 episode 9 (Flight of the Phoenix) during a card game (around 5 minutes in) Starbuck says, after the events in the Tomb of Athena;

> "... Earth is out there".

To which Racetrack responds,

> "We could all be chasing our tails over some half-ass planetarium show."

Again, likely talking about the events in the Tomb of Athena.